# C# polymorphous design without casting

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have Generator class that generates objects with different Interfaces with different probabilities. All objects generated by Generator  is of type `BaseClass`. `BaseClass` is an abstract base class.

Lets say interfaces are `I1`, `I2`

I have another class `Resolver` that has polymorphic method for two interfaces as follows:

`Resolve(I1 myObj){//code for I1}`

`Resolve(I2 myObj){//code for I2}`

The main class looks like this:

`BaseClass event = Generator.generate(); //event is implements I1 or I2. Not known what interfaces until run time.
Resolver.Resolve(event); //Here i got an error, because event is BaseClass type and not I1 or I2 type.`

Is there a way to solve this issue without explicitly check Interface type and cast it to appropriate interface. I came from python background, so statically typed language is new for me.

Comment: Yes, you can have a common interface "I" which is used as a base for BaseClass. I will have a  virtual function which will be overriden in the custom classes that derive from I1 and I2 respectively. For instance C1 from I1 and C2 from I2. Next you generate  either C1 or C2 in Generator. Then you don't need to check the type, you only have to call the virtual function. It will execute different code depending on the type of the class. Let me know if this makes sense so I can write a more illustrative answer.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Yes please.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using dependency injection to allow the event object to call the Resolver itself.

```
public interface IResolvable
{
    void Resolve(Resolver resolver);
}

public interface I1 : IResolvable { //... }
public interface I2 : IResolvable { //... }

public class Resolver
{
    public void Resolve(I1 i) { //... }
    public void Resolve(I2 i) { //... }
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IResolvable 
{ 
    public abstract void Resolve(Resolver resolver);
    //... 
}
```

An implementation would look something like:

```
public class Implementation1 : BaseClass, I1
{
    public override void Resolver(Resolver resolver)
    {
         resolver.Resolve(this);
    }
    //...
}
```

And then calling it:

```
Resolver resolver = new Resolver();
IResolvable evnt = Generator.Generate();
evnt.Resolve(resolver);
```

We can go a step further and make an interface for Resolver, so we can mock it for unit testing purposes and take full advantage of the DI pattern.

```
public interface IResolver
{
    void Resolve(I1 i) { //... }
    void Resolve(I2 i) { //... }
}
```

Then we change the definition of IResolvable

```
public interface IResolvable
{
    void Resolve(IResolver resolver);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that demonstrates virtual function approach that doesn't need casting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
interface IBase
{
    void Function();
}

class BaseClass : IBase
{
    public virtual void Function()
    {
    }
}

interface I1: IBase
{

}

interface I2 : IBase
{

}

class C1: BaseClass, I1
{
    public override void Function()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from C1");
    }
}

class C2 : BaseClass, I1
{
    public override void Function()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from C2 !!!");
    }
}

static class Generator
{
    public static BaseClass generateC1()
    {
        return new C1();
    }

    public static BaseClass generateC2()
    {
        return new C2();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass b1 = Generator.generateC1();
        b1.Function();

        Console.WriteLine("-------");

        BaseClass b2 = Generator.generateC2();
        b2.Function();

        Console.WriteLine("End!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice, My stupid question is would it be to have instead of BaseClass b1 = Generator.generateC1();

        IBase b1 = Generator.generateC1();

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *I adjusted my answer because I did not understand the question correctly the first time.*

I think that you can not achieve exactly what you would like to without using casts. As far as I understand as soon as you reference the object you get from `Generator.generate()` by its base type it is not possible to access the object by its specialized type again without casting it.

I can think of two alternatives which might be interesting for you. One is using C# 7 pattern matching (which is a bit like using casts) and the other is using `dynamic`.

**Pattern matching**

```
using System;

namespace EventREsolver
{
    public interface IEvent { }

    public class Event1 : IEvent { }

    public class Event2 : IEvent { }

    public class Resolver
    {
        public void Resolve(IEvent theEvent)
        {
            switch (theEvent)
            {
                case Event1 e1: Resolve(e1); break;
                case Event2 e2: Resolve(e2); break;
                default: throw new ArgumentException("not a recognized type", nameof(theEvent));
            }   
        } 

        private void Resolve(Event1 theEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolve I1");
        }

        private void Resolve(Event2 theEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolve I2");
        }
    }

    public class Generator
    {
        int state = 0;

        public IEvent Generate()
        {
            if (state == 0)
            {
                state++;
                return new Event1();
            }
            return new Event2();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var generator = new Generator();
            var event1 = generator.Generate();
            var event2 = generator.Generate();

            var resolver = new Resolver();
            resolver.Resolve(event1);
            resolver.Resolve(event2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**`Dynamic`**

```
using System;

namespace EventREsolver
{
    public interface IEvent { }

    public class Event1 : IEvent { }

    public class Event2 : IEvent { }

    public class Resolver
    {
        public void Resolve(Event1 theEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolve I1");
        }

        public void Resolve(Event2 theEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolve I2");
        }
    }

    public class Generator
    {
        int state = 0;

        public IEvent Generate()
        {
            if (state == 0)
            {
                state++;
                return new Event1();
            }
            return new Event2();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var generator = new Generator();
            dynamic event1 = generator.Generate();
            dynamic event2 = generator.Generate();

            var resolver = new Resolver();
            resolver.Resolve(event1);
            resolver.Resolve(event2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very similar to my problem, but not the same. In my case Resolver will have  many Resolve methods with polymorphic signatures  for every I1, I2, ... interfaces. In different methods there are different code.

Comment: @Farseer: See my adjusted answer.

Comment: I wouldn't resort to `dynamic` so quickly. Anything that involves `dynamic` has to be resolved entirely at run-time, which will be slower, and the compiler can't protect you against obvious mistakes. VuVirt's suggestion (which essentially adds a virtual `Resolve` method to `BaseClass`) allows the compiler to verify that the method exists for all involved classes, and you don't have to do any type-checking.